# Why is my Python for inside a for not working?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm new to python and the examples I have seen dont answer my question.

Im trying to read in two files, hosts and domainlist, and append the contents of domainlist onto hosts, adds a period, and prints the results.

The code I have does this correctly for the first host but only prints the next two hosts with the period.

```
h = open('hosts', 'r')
s = open('domainlist', 'r')
for host in h.read().split():
    for domain in s.read().split('\n'):
        print host+"."+domain

h.close()
s.close()
```

This prints out the following

```
google.gov
google.com
google.net
google.org
google.co.uk
google.com.au
google.com.sg
yahoo.
dogpile.
```

The 'hosts' file contains the following hosts

```
google
yahoo
dogpile
```

The 'domainlist' contains the following

```
gov
com
net
org
co.uk
com.au
com.sg
```

Comment: You may not read the same file twice!

Comment: @RishavKundu: You can if you rewind the file using its `.seek()` method. :) For a small file like this it's better to just read it into a list, as mentioned below. But for processing a very large file it may be necessary to use `.seek()`.

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks! did not know that haha.

Answer (score 4):

Mutability is against you; the file referenced by `s` has already been read by the second iteration of the outer `for` loop.

Consider changing the second line to `s = open('domainlist', 'r').read().split('\n')` and the fourth line to `for domain in s:`. This will store the readout of the `domainlist` file and avoid you attempting to read the file multiple times.

Comment: @SDilmac *sigh* well if you wanted an answer that also encourages good style, I guess, yes, I could've strongly suggested more prevalent use of lvalue-like objects. :-/ Edited to say as such.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here:

```
for domain in s.read().split('\n'):
```

In the first iteration of your outer for loop, you read the file. In the second iteration, he file pointer is already at the end of the file, and thus you have nothing more to loop over. I suggest you read the file once at the beginning and then iterate over the list:

```
h = open('hosts', 'r')
s = open('domainlist', 'r')
domains = s.read().split('\n')

for host in h.read().split():
    for domain in domains:
        print host+"."+domain

h.close()
s.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

What's with all this splitting and reading?

Simple iteration over a file does not require use of `split()` nor `read()` - you can iterate directly over the file object. I also recommend use of `with`:

```
with open('hosts') as h, open('domainlist') as s:
    for host in h:
        for domain in s:
            print '{}.{}'.format(host.strip(), domain.strip())
        s.seek(0)
```

Note the use of `seek(0)` to return to the beginning of the domain file for each host.

**Output**

```
google.gov
google.com
google.net
google.org
google.co.uk
google.com.au
google.com.sg
yahoo.gov
yahoo.com
yahoo.net
yahoo.org
yahoo.co.uk
yahoo.com.au
yahoo.com.sg
dogpile.gov
dogpile.com
dogpile.net
dogpile.org
dogpile.co.uk
dogpile.com.au
dogpile.com.sg
```

Another way it to use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

with open('hosts') as h, open('domainlist') as s:
    print '\n'.join('.'.join(x.strip() for x in t) for t in product(h, s))
```

Comment: better coded.   newbies should learn it like this, too.  and learn to look for stuff already in python and the defaults like `strip()`.

Answer (score 1):

is this simple enough:

```
for host in open('hosts'):
    for domain in open('domainlist'):
        print host.strip()+'.'+domain.strip()
```

Comment: note that open() defaults to read and the files get closed when there are no more references to them

Comment: That is about as simple as it gets. I'd add only that you should explicitly close the files, or open them within a `with` statement.

Comment: Also, `seek(0)` is faster than reopening the file, however, that is completely negligible for the OP's data.

Comment: python gets used for big elegant programs where explicit close is always a good idea and good programming and simple quickies where i don't care about that

Comment: as a former c programer i like python as it can be used many ways